# how to general search from [array] of string

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb of recipes and I want to dynamically create a general search query resulting in:

```
{ $all: [/potato/i, /onion/i, /garlic/i, /chicken/i] }
```

Without quotation marks from a string like:

```
const str = 'potato onion garlic chicken'
```

I've attempted:

```
const arr = []
str.split(' ').forEach(element => {
  arr.push(`/${element}/i`)
})
console.log(arr)
```

The problem is I end up with strings:

```
//[ '/potato/i', '/onion/i', '/garlic/i', '/chicken/i' ]
```

**How do can I dynamically create this query without stringifying?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
const str = 'potato onion garlic chicken'
const arr = []
str.split(' ').forEach(element => {
    // arr.push(`/${element}/i`)
    arr.push(new RegExp(element, 'i'))
})
console.log(arr)  // [ /potato/i, /onion/i, /garlic/i, /chicken/i ]
```

You can test [here](https://repl.it/repls/DarkkhakiClosedScientist)

Answer (score 1):

Just a similar version I have tried:

```js
const foodArr = 'potato onion garlic chicken';
queryArr = [];

foodArr.split(' ').forEach(foodElem => {
    queryArr.push(new RegExp(`${foodElem}`, 'i'));
});

console.log(queryArr);
```